# GridView Adapter on Monodorid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-gridview, baseadapter, xamarin

I've been having a strange issue with a gridView which I populate from a list using a custom adapter.

Everything looks normal until the first page of the gridView is full and then some of the subsequent items are either missing or out of sync.

I've done two screen captures, the first with a single column, the second with two. As you can see, the first page is rendered correctly in both as pictured bellow:

Single column: http://screencast.com/t/mSoEsDf1cY

and

Two column: http://screencast.com/t/i6zfPLYf

I simplified the code to demonstrate the issue:

```
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    List<Item> _items = null;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        _items = new List<Item>();

        for ( int i =0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            Item newItem = new Item();
            newItem.Text = "Item " + i;
            newItem.Bitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeResource( this.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon );

            _items.Add( newItem );
        }

        GridView grid = FindViewById<GridView> (Resource.Id.gridView1);
        grid.SetNumColumns(2);

        ItemGridViewAdapter adapter = new ItemGridViewAdapter( this, _items);
        grid.Adapter = adapter;
    }

}

public class Item
{
    public Android.Graphics.Bitmap Bitmap { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class ItemGridViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<Item>
{
    private List<Item> _items = null;
    private Context _context = null;

    public override int Count {
        get {
            return _items.Count;
        }
    }

    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override Item this[int position] {
        get {
            return _items[position];
        }
    }

    public ItemGridViewAdapter (Context context, List<Item> items)
    {
        _items = items;
        _context = context;
    }

    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        //based on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

        RelativeLayout layout = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            layout = new RelativeLayout( _context );

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);

            ImageView image = new ImageView (_context);
            image.LayoutParameters = new Gallery.LayoutParams (150, 150);
            image.SetImageBitmap ( this[position].Bitmap );
            image.Id = 1;
            layout.AddView (image);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams title_lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            TextView title = new TextView (_context);
            title.Text = this[position].Text; 
            title.Id = 2;
            title.SetTextColor (Android.Graphics.Color.White);
            title_lp.AddRule (LayoutRules.RightOf, 1);
            title_lp.AddRule (LayoutRules.CenterVertical);
            layout.AddView (title, title_lp);

        } else {

            layout = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
        }

        return layout;
    }

}
```

Any ideas  would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reuses some random old item views without any modification here:

```
    layout = (RelativeLayout)convertView;
```

Your getView() should be modified to provide new values, which are function of position, for any view, no matter recycled or just created.

Consider the example here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html .

They do almost the same as you do in the "else" part. But after that, they provide a new value for the view - in their case, a new image:

```
} else {
    imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
}

// Analogous update is missing from your code.
// Set your view's image, text, etc. here:
imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

return imageView;
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! I don't think I could see the wood from the trees and must have overlooked the seemingly most significant single line of code. I've re-factored and it all now works perfectly. Many thanks!